# Executing JQuery after page load only after clicking a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link in my app that when clicked, leads to another page. I want to execute some JQuery on this new page after it loads, but *only if that specific link is clicked to get to the page*.

I have this JQuery:

```
    $('#new_to_topics').click(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#topic_guidelines').slideDown('normal');
            $('#topic_guidelines').addClass('on');
        });
    });
```

where `#new_to_topics` is the id of the link that leads to the new page and

```
$('#topic_guidelines').slideDown('normal');
$('#topic_guidelines').addClass('on');
```

is the JQuery code I want to execute on that new page. However, this does not work. How should I do this?

Comment: Do you really have different pages or is it actually some new element appearing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass a location hash to the new page, and then conditionally run some javascript based on that hash.

If my link was to `mynewpage.html#fromXlink` (this would show in the address bar)

My javascript on mynewpage.html could be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.hash == '#fromXlink') {
    $('#topic_guidelines').slideDown('normal');
    $('#topic_guidelines').addClass('on');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a variable to the query string i.e. somepage.aspx?fromthislink=true
and then pick that up in jquery.

[This shows how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

If it cam from that link then fire off your jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#window.name) to pass data to the target page (although I would prefer passing data in the hash, if possible).