# Transfer data from one HTML file to another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript, what I'm trying to do is from an HTML file I want to extract the things that set there and display it to another HTML file through JavaScript.

Here's what I've done so far to test it:
**testing.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" action="next.html" method="get">
name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="n">
<input type="submit" value="next" >
<button type="button" id="print" onClick="testJS()"> Print </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**next.html**

```
<head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" action="next.html" method="get">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="here">test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**asd.js**

```
function testJS()
{

var b = document.getElementById('name').value

document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b;

}
```

`test.html` -> `ads.js`(will extract value from the test.html and set to next.html) -> `next.html`

Comment: Look into jQuery's `load()` function.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you have a typo: `scr="asd.js"` should be `src="asd.js"`

Comment: Actually you can this just by using EHTML: https://github.com/Guseyn/EHTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a value from one HTML page to another using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267519/how-can-i-pass-a-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript)

Answer (score 47):

Try this code:

In testing.html

```js
<script>
function testJS() {
    var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
        url = 'http://path_to_your_html_files/next.html?name=' + encodeURIComponent(b);
    
    document.location.href = url;
}
</script>
```

And in next.html:

```js
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
}
</script>
```

Description: JavaScript does not have any specific feature to share data between different pages. However, there are some alternative ways to achieve it, e.g., using URL Parameters (I have used this approach in my code), cookies, localStorage, etc.

At first in the testing.html, store the name parameter in URL (?name=...). Then in the script of next.html, parse the URL and get all the params from previous page.

PS. I'm a non-native English speaker, will you please correct my message, if necessary.

Comment: You can use external JS, for example, `test.js`. Include in this file 2 functions: `testJS` (code block 1) and `onLoad` (code block 2, but replace `window.onload = function` with `function onLoad`).
In `testing.html` bind `testJS` function to button click action (`onClick="testJS()"`) and in `next.html` bind `onLoad` function to body onload action (`onload="onLoad"`)

Comment: You're a genius.

Comment: @ShounakRay can you please elaborate this code for me? I'm a beginner and I'm trying to achieve something similar in my practice but I am a little confused here.

Answer (score 25):

The old fashioned way of setting a global variable that persist between pages is to set the data in a Cookie. The modern way is to use Local Storage, which has a good browser support (IE8+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 4+, Android 2+, iPhone 2+). Using localStorage is as easy as using an array:

```
localStorage["key"] = value;

... in another page ...
value = localStorage["key"];
```

You can also attach event handlers to listen for changes, though the event API is slightly different between browsers. [More on the topic.](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: i will do this through an internal JS or external?

Comment: @newbie: it does not matter, you can put your JavaScript in the HTML itself, or link it from somewhere else, doesn't matter.

Comment: most simple solution :)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are talking about this js in browser environment (unlike others like nodejs), Unfortunately I think what you are trying to do isn't possible simply because this is not the way it is supposed to work.

Html pages are delivered to the browser via HTTP Protocol, which is a 'stateless' protocol. If you still needed to pass values in between pages, there could be 3 approaches:

1. Session Cookies
2. HTML5 LocalStorage
3. POST the variable in the url and retrieve them in next.html via `window` object

Comment: which option is better for passing the data

Comment: @ShailendraKushwah cookies, because LocalStorage isn't handy when it comes to production, and POSTing in the URL isn't secure and data could be read and accessed.

Comment: POST can be done with form submit, or with ajax https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244323/2914407

Answer (score 8):

With the Javascript **localStorage** class, you can use the default local storage of your browser to save (key,value) pairs and then retrieve these values on whichever page you need using the key.
Example - 
**Pageone.html -**

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("firstname", "Smith");
</script>
```

**Pagetwo.html -**

```
<script>
    var name=localStorage.getItem("firstname");
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can simply send the data using `window.location.href` first store the value to send from `testing.html` in the script tag, variable say

```
<script> 
  var data = value_to_send
  window.loaction.href="next.htm?data="+data
</script>
```

this is sending through a get request

Answer (score 5):

I use this to set Profile image on each page.

On first page set value as:

```
localStorage.setItem("imageurl", "ur image url");
```

or on second page get value as :

```
var imageurl=localStorage.getItem("imageurl");
document.getElementById("profilePic").src = (imageurl);
```

Answer (score 2):

HI im going to leave this here cz i cant comment due to restrictions but i found AlexFitiskin's answer  perfect, but a small correction was needed

```
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
```

This needed to be changed to

```
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.n;
```

I know that after five years the owner of the post will not find it of any importance but this is for people who might come across in the future .

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" scr="asd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" action="#" method="get">
name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="n">
<input type="submit" value="next" >
<button type="button" id="print" onClick="testJS()"> Print </button>
</form>

</body>
```

client side scripting

```
function testJS(){
var name = jQuery("#name").val();
jQuery.load("next.html",function(){
jQuery("#here").html(name);
});
}
```

jQuery is a js library and it simplifies its programming. So I recommend to use jQuery rathar then js. Here I just took value of input elemnt(id = name) on submit button click event ,then loaded the desired page(next.html), if the load function executes successfully i am calling a function which will put the data in desired place.

jquery load function http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

The following is a sample code to pass values from one page to another using html. Here the data from page1 is passed to page2 and it's retrieved by using javascript.

**1) page1.html**

```
<!-- Value passing one page to another 
     Author: Codemaker
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Page 1 - Codemaker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="page2.html">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=firstname size=10></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=lastname size=10></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age:</td>
                    <td><input type=text name=age size=10></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><input type=submit value="Submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2) page2.html**

```
<!-- Value passing one page to another 
     Author: Codemaker
-->

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Page 2 - Codemaker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function getParams(){
                var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
                var params = new Array();
                if (idx != -1) {
                    var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
                    for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
                        nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                        params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
                    }
                }
                return params;
            }
            params = getParams();
            firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
            lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
            age = unescape(params["age"]);
            document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");
            document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
            document.write("age = " + age + "<br>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can I pass these values outside of script block? below example     ```<h1>Pluralsight Training:PS:- Bank Account Details</h1>
    <h2>PS: Bank Account Details </h2>
    params = getParams();
    <p>Account # : params["accountNo"] </p>
    <p>Account Holder Name : params["accountHolderName"]</p>
    <p>Balance : params["balance"]</p>```

Answer (score 0):

I coded the answers from Alex Fitiskin, and added a bit of extra code.
I added a parameter to the onLoad function to get the form's submit event, and prevent it's default behaviour first.

Here's the code:

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" action="next.html" method="get" onsubmit="return testJS(event)">
        name:<input type="text" id="name" name="n">
        <input type="submit" value="next">
        <!-- <button type="button" id="print" onClick="testJS()"> Print </button> //Button not needed anymore -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**next.html**

```
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" action="next.html" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="here">test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function testJS(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
        url = 'http://path_to_next_location/next.html?name=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

    document.location.href = url;
}

function onLoad() {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {},
        tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
        tmp = params[i].split('=');
        data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
}

window.onload = onLoad;
```

This way the onload function will be replaced with the custom onLoad function, and the form will not be submitted the default way, but instead using the code inside the testJS function.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid localstorage use as data are not safe with get method.  Best option is to use script set to module and then export & import data via 2 js files to html file.   Variable value can be passed between pages using module method.