# Receiving returned message from web socket server to other html Page in same Tab

Tags: javascript, java, html, netbeans

I am new to java. I have a task to complete.
I have two Html files

page1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a onclick="send('hello');"><li>Hello</li></a>
        <script>
            var ws;
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Test/actions");
            function send(text){
                ws.send(text);
            }    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to show this text in other html file (Page2.html), when it is clicked in Page1.html. 
And I have to implement it using Java WebSocket Only.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to implement `websocket` callback method in your first `html`

```
    <script>
              var ws;
              ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Test/actions");
              function send(text){
                 ws.send(text);
               }

              ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
               console.log(data);
              url = 'http://your_html_file_path/second.html?value='+ 
                     encodeURIComponent(data);
               document.location.href = url;

               });    
         </script>
```

Then you can try below methods to pass your data to another page

```
 url = 'http://your_html_file_path/second.html?value='+ encodeURIComponent(data);
 document.location.href = url;
```

There are different ways. Please check below answers too.

[Passing Variable through JavaScript from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765666/passing-variable-through-javascript-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

[Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another)