# What is the best way to transfer one form data to another form in Angular 2 or generic web devlopment?

Tags: html, angular, web, angular2-forms

**I would like to know -**

- What are the different techniques to transfer one form data into another form in Angular 2 or in general web development?
- Pros/Cons of each technique and when to use what

**I have come to know the following different processes -**

- Using API (i.e. through query params). Example - https://www.jotform.com/help/351-How-to-Automatically-Pass-Form-Data-to-Another-Form
- Using HTML5 local storage or session storage

[Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another) lists down the options I have mentioned above.

I am a newbie in web development, so my knowledge is limited, but I am willing to handle complex process if that is more efficient than others.

Comment: Use reactive programming, appliacation storage and services. Also you can use a tool like ngrx instead of services.

Answer (score 0):

Time to learn about Services before trying to write a working app: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4