# How do I present a form to a client that includes their input data for their printing?

Tags: html, forms, printing

I want a site user to be able to print a "souvenir certificate" with their name embedded.

I've tried numerous approaches, but trial and error is producing more error than useful joy. There's going to be a bit more to this when I'm done, but I want to start on the right path, which I haven't found yet.

I presume the following functional steps:

1. Display a form. Included in the formatted text, the form contains one "current date" {now} field and a field to manually add data to- the user's name - and an "update" button.
2. When the update button is clicked, it verifies the form has the name data added and..

   (a) if incorrect, returns the default form and focuses the
    incorrect field for completion
   (b) if correct, proceeds to step 3
3. Presents the completed form as a new window (or in the same window), with a button that says "print"
4. When the print button is pushed, it prints the form on the users default printer (or opens the client's print dialog box for them to print the form).

"Certificate" font is courier new throughout, no graphics, but is formatted like a letter (from/to head w/date -{now}-, several paragraphs of text, closing signature).

To quote Jimmy Buffet, "It's so dang simple, like the jitter-bug, it plumb escapes me.."

I prefer html/5 if possible - simpler is better (maintainance in the future may be performed by others even less knowledgeable than I), and not opening a security hole to my server.

Comment: Welcome, please take a moment to read [ask], especially the part "Help others reproduce the problem". The question as it stands makes it look like you want us to write code for you, which we're happy to do, but would appreciate if you took some time to try it yourself. We're all volunteers here, and this sounds like something one might get paid for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Trust me - nobody is paying me for this, and there's no budget for anyone else, I haven't built a site in 8 years, and the only one in the group with any experience at all. This, however, is novel to me, I could put up all sorts of failed coding attempts, which should be good for laughs, but not much else. I AM hoping for some core code or guidance I can run with in the right direction and not run into a brick wall half way there..I'm not even sure I should try to force it with html form code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the basic action I'm trying to establish is get data in one html (form) page and send it to another, it appears local storage or session storage is the key, and is the starting point to accomplishing what I want to do. (*My "latest guide" was Lincoln Stein's guide on HTML 3.2, which was sufficient for all I was trying to do up until this brilliant idea I had. I'm not a programmer, I'm a retired old-school hardware guy trying to do some folks a favor.*)

Fortunately, a duckduckgo query (not a search here) pointed me to: 
[Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another)

Once I saw the code samples, it made sense. Thanks to the contributors there. Off I shall go and close this question.