# Send Data one page to another page in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I try to send data from one page to another HTML page. I tried with the window.load method and localStorage but unable to get the output. I have a table with title and button when click on button current row title will be displayed in the b.html page. Can anyone suggest me in the right direction.

a.html

```
<body>
 <table class="at-items-block">
  <thead></thead>
   <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td class="at-int-sn">
        <h2 class="at-IntHdr">test</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><b>bbb</b> bbb</li>
            <li><b>bb</b> bb</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="at-int-dl1">
        <h2>6.2<span class="time-sep">hrs</span></h2>
        <span class="todownload">to download*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="at-int-dl2">
        <h2>55<span class="time-sep">min</span></h2>
        <span class="todownload">to download*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="at-int-dl3">
        <h2 class="at-IntHdr">11<span class="time-sep">min</span></h2>
        <span class="todownload">to download*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="at-int-price">
        <h2 class="atr"><span>$</span>1444<span class="per-month"> per mon*</span></h2>
        <span class="check-info">text here<br>
        text here<br>
        text here</span>
    </td>
    <td class="at-item-btn"><a href="b.html" class="at-int-btn">send</a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="at-item">
    <h2 class="at-title">Title2 Here</h2>
  </td>
  <td class="at-item-btn"><a href="b.html">send</a></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
  <script>
   window.onload = function() {
   var getTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("at-title");
  localStorage.setItem("itemsTitle",getTitle);
}
</script>
```

b.html

```
<div class="titleFetch">
<div class="titleHere"></div>
<div class="check-info"></div>
</div>
  </body>
 <script>
  window.onload = document.getElementsByClassName("titleFetch").innerHTML = 
  localStorage.getItem("itemsTitle");
  </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("at-title")` returns a HTMLCollection object. You've to get the first element in the collection, and read its `innerHTML` when setting the value to LocalStorage, and the same when you're setting `innerHTML` on the other page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return . But Blackturtok's idea of passing the title in a querystring in the address is also very useful.

Comment: @sanojlawrence In suggested url using get method fetching data but here I'm not using form my question is using div's how to fetch data

Comment: @Husna, Look at the answer below, It should solve your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JS` which you have provided in `index.html` (first html) page will not do the things, you need to replace it with the following,

```
    window.onload = function() {

    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.at-item-btn');

    const passData = (getTitle) => {
        localStorage.setItem("itemsTitle",getTitle);
    }

    buttons.forEach((el,i) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', passData.bind(this, el.previousElementSibling.textContent))
    })

 }
```

Here you need to get all the buttons and need to make [**addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for each button and pass the respective title as parameter to the function and set it in localstorage setItem like,

```
const passData = (getTitle) => {
    localStorage.setItem("itemsTitle",getTitle);
}
```

Then in `b.html`, change the script to replace the received title like,

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("titleFetch")[0].textContent =
    localStorage.getItem("itemsTitle");
}
```

> [**Working example here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cKbyDl6LTufxWlR1h5lm?p=preview)

Comment: exactly what I want thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I have mutiple `td 's ` here only the last td data is coming. And only selected td i want to display using the class name. Can you suggest to me.

Comment: @Husna, I couldn't understand you.. Can you fork the example provided above and replicate how actual your table structure looks like and explain in clear about your exact requirement..

Comment: I don't know whether this is what you are asking to find the nearest ```at-title``` of the clicked button.. You can replace the function declartion parameter like ```passData.bind(this, el.closest('tr').querySelector('.at-title').textContent``` .. http://plnkr.co/edit/gNZOxir75TiGgIZCJ6Gr?p=preview

Comment: i updated my question here i want to display `at-IntHdr` and `at-int-price`

Comment: @Husna, The above mentioned  ```at-IntHdr``` is itself inside ```at-int-price``` and ```at-int-price``` doesn't have any text so what should you want in ```at-int-price```?? Really it is confusing for me.. On click of the send button what should you need to send to ```b.html```?? Give right appropriate answer..

Comment: I want to display `at-IntHdr` and complete `at-int-price` td this two td's

Comment: @Husna, I could only find td's with class name ```at-int-price``` and the class ```at-IntHdr``` is given only for ```h2``` elements..

Comment: Can we do like this `at-int-sn` nearest element.

Comment: @Husna, Do you need like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/HDs3mhtmphsmi3cPg3yk?p=preview

Comment: How to pass multiple classes here `querySelector('.at-IntHdr')`

Comment: @Husna, I have made a sample here http://plnkr.co/edit/1EPNRg7KwCEcuZ8FyjGn?p=preview based on the inputs given by you.. Displayed the ```$1444 per mon*```(from price td) and ```test```(from at-int-sn td).. And this is all I can do for now.. For further adjustments you need to understand the implementation and tweak it yourself and it is not a big deal if you understand.. Happy coding !!!..

Comment: I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

In my Opinion the best way would be the PHP-GET methods (example how to in PHP)

```
$var = $_GET['mode']
//to Use this you have to change your link, for example b.html?mode=YourString
//here you have the string right from the '='-character
```

alternatively if you want to use this method with JavaScript-Only you can use this method

```
let endingString = "";
let workingString = window.location.href;
let boolpath = false;

for(var i = 0; i < workingString.length; i++)
{
    if (boolpath)
    {
        endingString += workingString[i];
    }
    else if (workingString[i] == '?') {
        boolpath = true;
    }        
}
//to Use this you have to change your link, for example b.html?hallo123
//here you have the complete string in the right of the '?'-mark
//b.html?hallo123 -> endingString="hallo123"
```

I personally recommend the JavaScript-aproach