# How can I send text from a.html to b.html

Tags: javascript

It is possible that the input text is sent to the second page with the help of javascript.

I need suggestions, help how I can send the text from a.html to b.html

Cod a.HTML

```
<input type="text" >
<button>send</button>
```

Cod b.HTML

```
<p id="mytxt">
  <!-- text from a.html -->
</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another)

Comment: It's not the first time I've written about this. Why write the same question twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the query part of the URL to "send" data to another page:

`a.html`:

```html
<form action="b.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="mytext">
    <button>send</button>
</form>
```

`b.html`:

```html
<p id="mytxt"></p>
<script> 
    document.getElementById('mytxt').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('mytext')))
</script>
```

However, this has its own limits. E.g. [URL's length should be under 2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/8376184), and if somebody revisits the generated link, the same text will appear.

If you have access to some server-side language/configuration, you can make a `POST` request instead, and manipulate `b.html` on the server.

If you have to stick to front-end, you could also try something with the Session Storage, and a redirection using JS.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is basically how forms work. You wrap your input and button in a form tag with the attributes method="get" and action="b.html". Inside of b.html you can read the submitted data from the URL.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get parameters. When going to b.html, set a get parameter `b.html?text=SOME_TEXT`

and in b.html using js to get parameter:

```
let url = new URL(window.loacation.href);
let text = url.searchParams.get("text");
document.getElementById('mytxt').innerText = text
```

Comment: Thank you very much