# how to pass value one page to another page using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Hi I have a Pricing table that was created in javascript, what I need to know is how to pass the values in row 1 or 2 into a aspx page using javascript with the click of a button

Here my code:

```
 <select style="padding:10px;background: #cb1c69;color: #FFFFFF; font-size:18px; border-radius: 11px;">
                        <option>Choose Your Plan</option>
                        <option value="red">Monthly</option>
                        <option value="green">Yearly</option>
                        <option value="blue">Perpetual</option>
                    </select>
```

Edition:

```
<div class="pricetable-column  red box" style="width: 33.3333333333%; border-right:1px solid gray;">
                            <div class="pricetable-column-wall">
                                <div class="pricetable-header">
                                    <div class="pricetable-fld-name">
                                        Lite</div>
                                    <div class="pricetable-header-inner">
                                        <div class="pricetable-fld-price">
                                            <span class="cur"></span>750/- Monthly</div>
                                        <p>
                                            ( Minimum 6 Month)</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ribbon">
                                    HOT</div>
                                <div class="pricetable-button-container1">
                                    <a href="#">Buy Now</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I want if i click the buy now button and value get go to another page. I mean billing options page

please help me sir

I don't know how to use javascript.

update code:

Source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   Name:
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" value="Mudassar Khan" /><br />
<br />
Technology:
<select id="ddlTechnolgy" name="Technology">
    <option value="ASP.Net">ASP.Net</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="JSP">JSP</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnQueryString" value="Send" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
            var url = "MyPage2.html?name=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtName").val()) + "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent($("#ddlTechnolgy").val());
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Destination Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["name"] != null && queryString["technology"] != null) {
            var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
            data += "<b>Name:</b> " + queryString["name"] + " <b>Technology:</b> " + queryString["technology"];
            $("#lblData").html(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any problem my code:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267519/how-can-i-pass-a-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript

Comment: sir i don't know sir javascript if u don't mind can you run the code in jsfiddle@eugensunic

Comment: If you do not know JS you need to go to rentacoder - this site is not for gimmetehcodez type questions

Comment: Now i try Source Page:  and Destination Page

Comment: First page work but second page not opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plese try this code according to your requirement:

**Source Page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name:
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" value="Mudassar Khan" /><br />
<br />
Technology:
<select id="ddlTechnolgy" name="Technology">
    <option value="ASP.Net">ASP.Net</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="JSP">JSP</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnQueryString" value="Send" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
            var url = "Page2.htm?name=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtName").val()) + "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent($("#ddlTechnolgy").val());
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Destination Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id = "lblData"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["name"] != null && queryString["technology"] != null) {
            var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
            data += "<b>Name:</b> " + queryString["name"] + " <b>Technology:</b> " + queryString["technology"];
            $("#lblData").html(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I click send button open second page but not display the value

Comment: @dotnet pls explain what you did

Comment: Hi,
Here i am used querystring.
The Source Page has an HTML Button with a jQuery Click event handler. When the Button is clicked, the values of the Name TextBox and the Technology DropDownList is set as QueryString Parameter and then the page is redirected to the Destination page

Comment: Now i try Source Page: and Destination Page . First page work but second page value not opened.what can i do sir.

Comment: Please go through this url this will help you:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Pass-Data-Values-from-one-page-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: If this question like you then please upvote my question@DotNetWeblineindia

Comment: I like your question and i also upvote it.@Jenita mary

Comment: Thank u Sir@DotNetWeblineindia

Answer (score 1):

> You have multiple options to do so:

1. **sessionStorage**

Example:

`sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');//to set value
 sessionStorage.getItem('key');//to get the value`

2. **localStorage**

Example:

`localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');//to set value
localStorage.getItem('key');//to get the value`

3. **Cookies**

Example: [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

4. **As a key in Query string**

Ex:

`http://www.example.com?myKey=myVal`

Comment: i can understand sir but i don't know javascript. what can i do sir

Comment: JSFiddle cannot easily show how this works over two pages

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass values that a user selects in one page to another page. I would recommend you to pass your values using key value pairs in the URL. JavaScript has neat way of doing it. For example :

`var month = "July"
 var date = "1"
 var URL = "yourpage.aspx?month="+month+"&date="+date
 location.href=URL`

By this, the URL will look something like this `youpage.aspx?month=July&date=1`
The parameters in the URL start after the question mark "?" and the key value pairs are separated by "&". location.href will redirect your page to that URL. and then you can read these parameters using .net on the server side. I hope this helps.