# Changing Element on Another Html Page When Transitioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have came across some challenge trying to generate text  in another html page after clicking pagetext on initial page in the same site. Below is the set code - a script on the initial index page. Upon clicking the element i would like the text to be changed on details.html page (in this case just print "Goodbye") for testing first.

How can i tell javascript/jscript to change text on the element #dtitle on the other page?

```
$('details.html #dtitle')
```

this one obviously doesnt work - only moves to the second page. Is there any syntax?

```
function toTransit() {
    location.href='details.html';
    $('details.html #dtitle').html('Goodbye');          
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"How can i tell javascript/jscript to change text on the element #dtitle on the other page?"_ You can't.  You'll need to _at least_ run some javascript on the following page, plus [utilise a method to pass the text you want from the first page to the next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267519/how-can-i-pass-a-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript).

Comment: thank you for you reply.