# Send the user to a page along with a error message

Tags: redirect, authentication, error-handling

I want to set up a login page in which from anywhere on the site I can send a user to it and it will display a custom message along with it. I could use a redirect and a `msg` query param but is this the best way to do it?

I'm working with node.js but I'm interested in a universal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going for easy, you can just have GET data in the URL. But, that doesn't look that nice, if you want a rather long message, plus, GET has size restrictions, where POST (virtually) hasn't.
For using post data you could use the solution of this: [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) question, but that gives a rather messy source code (if you want a somewhat longer text).
You could keep them in a database, and only send the ID of the message to a PHP page, and get it from the database (that's what I would do, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea, just amateur here!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery or simply plain javascript to extract your message from the url; the relevant question that listed links to detailed code: [jquery get querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url).

Then depending on how you want it displayed, apply the extracted string to your situation.