# Javascript redirect to different url parameter

Tags: javascript, loops, redirect, parameters

How can I get the URL parameters of the current page? This is for a userscript that I want to redirect the user to a different url if current url parameter equals a predefined parameter. I want the script to loop between 3 set pages.

The urls look like this: example.com/pages?car=1

I have no idea whatsoever how to do this, but this is somewhat how

```
if(url is ?car=1){
   wait 5 seconds;
   redirect to ?car=2;
}elseif(url is ?car=2){
   wait 5 seconds;
   redirect to ?car=3;
}elseif(url is ?car=3){
   wait 5 seconds;
   redirect to ?car=1;
}
```

Comment: You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: Take a look at this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` to redirect the user to different url

And read this to get the values from query string.

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)