# handle request parameter on html page call through ajax

Tags: ajax, html

I have to handle request parameter on html page which is called by Ajax Request.
My Code is:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "abc.html",
   data: "cat=1",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(data) {
   $("#div").html(data);

  }
});
```

Now on abc.html page, I want to use "cat" request parameter.
How its possible?

Comment: Which is the server side language? ASP.Net / PHP / Perl / CF?

Comment: i have to implement it by jquery mobile for phonegap App. so not using  any server side language because data is only in xml.so just using javascript, html & css

Comment: found any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link may help you - http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Source : [jquery get querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

Comment: I have alredy tried it.. It not works with Ajax Request.just giving undefined result.