# get value of a php variable set by url in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

Hey i defined a php variable like this inside the body tag:

```
<?php $v=null;?>
```

Now i am using this code to check if the variable is set through the url

```
if ("<?php echo $_GET["v"];?>;"  == null) {
          // Do something because the variable is set through the url

    }
 else {
         // Do something else because the variable is not set through the url    
    }
```

I am using an url like this: www.example.com/index.php?v=12345

When i run this code by opening the index with this url it says v is undefined..
When i run this code by opening the index with "www.example.com/index.php" it is undefined as well.. but not 'null'

What is the problem here? Thank you

Comment: assign <?php echo $_GET["v"];?> this to any javascript variable. var v=<?php echo $_GET["v"];?> ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
var my_var_arr = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=');
if (my_var_arr[1]  == null) {
      // Do something because the variable is set through the url

}
else {
     // Do something else because the variable is not set through the url    
}
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aXDbG/)

Comment: I´ve tried this before many times.. it did not change something

Comment: works if nothing is set through the url, but if the url is like www.example.com/index.php?v=1234 is returns ?v,1234 ... i want just to return 1234 .. how can i do that?

Comment: Oh ok I got it.See now

Comment: Ok the fiddle helped, i mixed it with "document.URL" to get the url.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to get the query string parameter instead of php. There is lot of tutorials around here.

Ref: http://javascriptproductivity.blogspot.in/2013/02/get-url-variables-with-javascript.html

Possible solution: [jquery get querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

Comment: Do i need to modify the .htaccess for that?

Comment: No need for changing htaccess