# How to retrieve PHP $_GET using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an app running on `localhost/index.php`
In Javascript I use a History API: `history.replaceState({}, null, "?uid=" + uid);` to change the URL of my page (`uid` is a variable with randomly generated value). After this manipulations address was updated to `localhost/index.php?uid=dqw12312aws`, for example.
Then I try to receive a `uid` variable on server side by: `console.log('<?php echo "$_GET[uid]"; ?>');`. 
But I obtain an unexpected value.
My first request to `localhost/index.php?uid=dqw12312av` - `$_GET[uid]` will be  an empty string.
But my second request to `localhost/index.php?uid=qwtgas23123` for example - `$GET[uid]` will be a value of my first request and equal `dqw12312aws` and so on. Why is this happening?

Comment: The entire point of `history.replaceState` is that it *does not* load a new page from the server. So running code on the server to detect will not work.

Comment: And what should I do, if I want to change my URL without page reloading, and transmit `var uid` to PHP via GET method.

Comment: ^^ Use `history.replaceState` to change the variable and then ***AJAX*** it back to the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `console.log('<?php echo $_GET["uid"]; ?>');` in javascript, correct?. Javascript is not on the server side. Javascript get interpreted by the browser. The PHP is interpreted by the server, I.E. PHP is server side. Server side means that the code *only* gets interpreted when the server side-file is run **by the server**. (I.E. when the page is loaded).

> When you load the PHP file you basically ask the server to go into the file, find any PHP and execute it.

This means, in this case, that `$_GET['uid']` will contain the `uid` url-param that was set when the page was loaded. So

> `$_GET['uid']` will not change when the URL is changed dynamically via javascript. Because:
>   *The page isn't refreshed* → *The PHP file does not run* → *PHP code doesn't get evaluated again.*

---

You could solve this by retrieving the URL-query string by using javascript.
E.G.

```
function getUrlVar(requestedKey) {
    var hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        var key = hash[0],
            val = hash[1];
        if (key === requestedKey) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var uid = getUrlVar("uid");
```

If you have this URL in the browser: `http://localhost/index.php?uid=1234`
Then the `uid` variable in the code above contains `1234`

[JS Function source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

---

In a comment below you asked me how to send a get variable to PHP.

To run a PHP-script without refreshing the page, you could use dynamic requests. E.G. ajax.
If you are new to web-scripting and javascript, I recommend you take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So you would include jQuery in your index.php and run this JS code:

```
function getUrlVar(requestedKey) {
    var hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        var key = hash[0],
            val = hash[1];
        if (key === requestedKey) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function sendUidToPHP(){
    $.post("receiver.php", {uid: getUrlVar("uid")}, function(data){
        // The data argument now contains the response from php
        // To learn more about this see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax
        // and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post
    });
}
```

The receiver.php would be able to read the `uid` from `$_POST['uid']`.

---

One more thing. If the `uid` URL-param is the only thing needed to log in to another user, then your script has a **HUGE** security flaw. Take a look at [PHP-Cookies](http://www.php-learn-it.com/php_cookies.html) and [PHP-Sessions](http://www.php-learn-it.com/php_sessions.html)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `vars` array in that code sample?

Comment: It's a modified code i got from another question. I will clean it up and add source. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I want to transmit an `uid` variable in JS to PHP over GET method.

Comment: Then you should clarify, and ask for that in your question. I have extended the answer pretty much. Maybe you will understand how it works by reading it now :)

Comment: The bottom part now contains how to send the `uid` from javascript to PHP.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Assuming the OP is using ajax. This may not be the best assumption, as it was not tagged with jQuery in the question...

Comment: I am not assuming he is. Did you even read my answer? I added that part as a request from him in the comment right above yours.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Thanks for so meticulous clarifications. This example is useful for me. I didn't want to refuse from GET it seems more gracefully but it turned non-working.