# Pass data to other window, like google does js

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

How could i pass some data to my window.open() ?
For example:
I am in `site1.com` and using 
`window.open("http://site2.com");`

The questing is - how to crossbrowser pass some data via js to that `site1.com`

Comment: You can use the querystring `http://example.com/?foo=bar`

Comment: `like google does js`, Google doesn't *do* JS, please clarify...

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan and if you have large data you can post data to site2.com using java-script.

Comment: you can find your answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Comment: the goal is to pass data BACK to `site1.com` via opened poup `site2.com`. See the example here http://take.ms/1ukeT

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass data between pages is to build a query string like this:

```
window.open("http://site2.com?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar&etc=whatever");
```

Comment: the goal is to pass data BACK to site1.com via opened poup site2.com. See the example here take.ms/1ukeT

Answer (score 0):

When one page opens another the function window.opener() can return values to a particular function in the opening page.  Look it up for details.  I don't have a development box in front of me so its difficult to show good examples.  I know I've done it this way in the past.  Like a popup allowing choices to be made by user then close child form and pass choice back to parent form.

Comment: Unfortunately window.opener is only working for same domain. If i try to change something in the other domain it is going to be an error: `"SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://site2.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame."`