# how to prepopulate a form by url?

Tags: php, jquery, html, url

hello i have This form in domain.com/inicio

```
<form id="myForm" action="/%27/ajaxform" method="POST" >
  <select id="tiendaseleccionada" style="width: 350px;">
                 <option value="0"
           >
           Seleccione CDD...
        </option>
                 <option value="1"
           >
           Centro de Distribución Directa &quot;1&quot;
        </option>
                 <option value="2"
           >
           Centro de Distribución Directa &quot;2&quot;
        </option>
                 <option value="3"
           >
           Centro de Distribución Directa &quot;3&quot;
        </option>
                 <option value="4"
           >
           Centro de Distribución Directa &quot;4&quot;
        </option>
                 <option value="5"
           >
           Centro de Distribución Directa &quot;5&quot;
        </option>
                 <option value="6"
           >
           Centro de Distribución Directa &quot;6&quot;
        </option>
           </select>
  <img src="/img/loadin2.ajax.gif" style="display: none;" id="imggif">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#tiendaseleccionada option[value='0']").attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
  /*var lista = document.getElementById('tiendaseleccionada');

lista.onchange = function() {
var url = lista.options[lista.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-url');
window.location = url;
};*/
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Verificar disponibilidad" hidden="true"/>
</form>
```

ok, then I need to prepopulate just using the url to when page loads it loads with value 2 example. hope there is any way I can do this. I have been searching for this for a long time :)

thanks you.

Comment: Cannot be done until you don't own the site, this is not like hashes which you can include in your url and correspond to a dom element having id, such as http://example.org/page.php#section-x

Answer (score 0):

With an URL like this:

```
mydomain.com/mypage#2
```

You can then read the hash value:

```
var sel = document.location.hash;
```

Then you can set the selectedIndex of your SELECT statement based on that value.

Comment: no what i need, i dont own the site, i just need a url to access and prepopulate the select field.

Comment: The site will only behave the way the builder intended. There is no URL backdoor to make it behave the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your JQuery version, the Javascript portion of what you're trying to do should be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#tiendaseleccionada").val(2);
});
```

To dynamically get the select value (2 in the example above) you can read values from the URL querystring:

[jquery get querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the other two answers for clarity:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var sel = document.location.hash;
  jQuery("#tiendaseleccionada").prop('selectedIndex', sel);
});
```

The code above should get the hash from the end of the URL and then use that value to change the selected index to that index.

It's a little unclear what the exact answer to your issue is unless you provide the specific format of the URL. If you clarify a little more I'll edit my answer.