# Get query string from URL with jQuery and do action based on that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link in an e-mail that points the user to a webpage. On this webpage there is a pop-up that is hidden, unless a button is clicked; then jQuery displays that div.

I have searched for a way to grab the query string from the URL with jQuery to no avail. I know with PHP it would be a simple $query = $_GET['query'], but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with jQuery.

I need to check for a query string, say "?popUp=true", and display that div with jQuery if the query string is present.

Is there a way I can pass the PHP GET variable to jQuery? 
I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has nothing to do with it; it's just plain Javascript:

```
var query = window.location.search;
```

Or simply `location.search`. Do `window.location` from the Javascript console to see [what all is there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (location.search.indexOf('popUp=true') > -1)) {
        doPopUp(); // run your code.
    }
});
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Comment: I saw this solution similarly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url). But I'm still not clear on how jQuery can check if javascript found the query string?

Comment: On page load/ready, check for your query (`if (window.location.search.indexOf('your=stuff') > -1)`) and run the code that opens your pop-up. Note, if that's a *window* pop-up, running that automatically is going to be difficult (since window pop-ups are, y'know frowned on and generally hated).

Comment: This seemed promising, but I can't quite figure out why its not currently working. 

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if (location.search.indexOf('popUp=true') > -1)) {
         document.getElementById('div#optionBG','div#optionBG2').style.display = 'block';
      }
  });
 </script>`

Comment: You're using `document.getElementById()` incorrectly; you would only pass one ID text at a time (`optionBG`). However, use jQuery: `$('div#optionBG, div#optionBG2').show();`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, we can get query parameter from url by split it, and it's pure java script. There's a general way to do it: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html

But if you just need [popup=true] to use with jquery, you'd better to use hash.

URL:

```
http://.../yourscript.php#popup
```

And your jquery code:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
 // Fragment exists, show popup
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist, do nothing
}
```