# Html element display none inline in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to `display:none` html element in **asp.net** something like this :)

```
<ul style="<% if(Page.Request.QueryString["Search"] == null) { "display: none"} %>">
```

Any suggestion or example would be great for me, thanks.

Comment: You can define the `RunAs` attribute  to `server` and take care of this in the code behind. Or do you really prefer ot stay in the HTML ?

Comment: I dont want to define "RunAs" :)

Comment: Then i'd say @Legends answer is your solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
<% = (Page.Request.QueryString["Search"] == null ? "display:none":string.Empty) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript for this? It will be much cleaner to keep client side code separate.

there are a ton of ways to get a query string in JS here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

Then you can check and add the class with jquery.

HTML:

```
<ul id="search">

    <li>test</li>

</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    var search = getUrlVars()["Search"];

    if(!search)
    {
        $("#search").css("display","none")
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aaLw9mx8/