# "[], hash" syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. In the following code snippet (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)), what does the `[], hash` syntax mean? I searched a bit but no luck.

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;// <============= HERE
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: `var vars = []` is defining an empty array called `vars`, and `hash` is a local variable with a value of `undefined`. It's the same as `var vars = [];` and `var hash;`.

Comment: as far as the rest of the code is concerned, it's a bit of a wreck: two `var` statements with one having multiple declarations, incorrectly parsing the URL for the query string (could just be `location.search`), [incorrectly parsing the query string](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell), trying to use an array as a hash map instead of an object. Get rid of this code and use a lib.

Comment: @zzzzBov I am trying do some common tasks on a page, such as get query string parameters. Any lib to recommend? I am not quite familiar with the JavaScript landscope.

Comment: In NPM land (node, browserify, etc) the [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) library is solid enough for most usage, but there are some edge cases that it doesn't handle, so [I wrote my own querysting parsing lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystringjs) which uses UMD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a normal declaration of multiple variables

```
var vars = [], hash;
```

is same as

```
var vars = [];
var hash;
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

**Syntax:**

```
var varname1 [= value1 [, varname2 [, varname3 ... [, varnameN]]]];
```

Comment: It seems `vars` are intended to use as `dictionary`. But based on my limited knowledge about JS object, it's better not to use a true array. right?

Comment: @smwikipedia `vars` is an array, in JS everything(well, _not everything_) is an object, so you can also assign properties to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at `[], hash` when you should be looking at the entire line, which is:

```
var vars = [], hash;
```

In its entirety, you have a variable declaration, which takes a comma separated list of variable names. Those names being `vars` and `hash`, which would be better formatted as:

```
var vars,
    hash;
```

And within that declaration you have a variable assignment to the `vars` variable.

`[]` is an array literal in JavaScript. So in the end you have declared `vars`, initialized it with a value of a new empty array, and declared `hash` without initializing it (value will be `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

That code just combined these two concepts to make the code impossible to understand for newbies:

1.
There are 2 ways to declare an Array:

```
// 1 (old school)
var myArray = new Array();

// 2 (the easiest and most common)
var myArray = [];
```

2.
You can declare multiple variables (with or without setting their values) in one swoop using a comma:

```
// Declaring 3 variables
var a, b, c;
// or
var a=1, b=2, c=3;
```