# Getting a query string in a url if exists in javascript

Tags: javascript

It seems there's no easy and built-in way to check whether an url contains a query string and if it does, get it. The approaches I found so far rely on "url.indexOf("?")" and regex. Are these the only ways, isn't in Javascript there anything like "url.queryString" property?

Comment: There is not... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: You can use a custom function like [this example](http://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/)

Comment: If you're not afraid of 3rd party dependencies, try this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no direct way to do that, or no built in functionality is provided by JS to do this, but there are many relatively straight forward approaches to do this, **Like this one:**

```
var field = "anyquery";
var _status = window.location.href.indexOf('?' + field + '=');

if(_status!=-1){
   // Field Exists!
}
```

**Or even this one:** ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656873/1496715))

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

You can check using `getUrlVars().hasOwnProperty("anyquery");`

and the value can be fetched using `getUrlVars().anyquery`

and the `array` of all the `query` can be `Object.keys(getUrlVars());`