# Checking JavaScript AJAX loaded resources with Mink/Zombie in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, mink, zombie.js

I'm trying to test a page, which otherwise uses massive asynchronously loaded JavaScript resources, with PHP script that uses Mink and Zombie. Unfortunately, this process fails (leaving behind [hanging processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482891/php-mink-zombie-handling-hanging-processes-after-a-fatal-exception)). I have managed finally to simulate this error on a minimal example, which I'll post here.

The first page - the page to be tested - is basically a [self-contained file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463252/possible-to-have-a-self-contained-js-html-jquery-file-that-emulates-an-ajax-c), that simulates the AJAX calls by calling itself:

**`test_JSload.php`**

```php
<?php
if (array_key_exists("QUERY_STRING", $_SERVER)) {
  if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "getone") {
    echo "<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src='test_JSload.php?gettwo'></script>
  </head>
  </html>
  ";
    exit;
  }

  if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "gettwo") {
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo "
  function person(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.changeName = function (name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    };
  }
  ";
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
.my_btn { background-color:yellow; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var thishref = window.location.href.slice(0, window.location.href.indexOf('?')+1);
var qstr = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?')+1);

function OnGetdata(inbtn) {
  console.log("OnGetdata; loading ?getone via AJAX call");
  //~ $.ajax(thishref + "?getone", { // works
  var ptest = {}; // init as empty object
  console.log(" ptest pre ajax is ", ptest);

  $.ajax({url: thishref + "?getone",
    async: true, // still "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated", because we load a script; https://stackoverflow.com/q/24639335
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("got getone data "); //, data);
      $("#dataholder").html(data);
      ptest = new person("AHA");
      console.log(" ptest post getone is ", ptest);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log("getone error " + thishref + " : " + xhr.status + " / " + thrownError);
    }
  });

  ptest.changeName("Somename");
  console.log(" ptest post ajax is ", ptest);
}

ondocready = function() {
  $("#getdatabtn").click(function(){
    OnGetdata(this);
  });
}
$(document).ready(ondocready);
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <button type="button" id="getdatabtn" class="my_btn">Get Data!</button>
  <div id="dataholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when the page first loads, there's no action; and as soon as the button is pressed: first some HTML content, which contains `<script>`, is returned (this is `?getone`) through an AJAX call; then this script itself loads "automatically" from `?gettwo`. I'm aware this is probably not the right thing to do (see [JavaScript console.log causes error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr)), but there is a similar organization in the actual page I'm trying to test.

To run this page, you can just have the command-line `php` version > 5.3, and run in the same directory of the file:

```bash
php -S localhost:8080
```

... and then, in a browser, go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php`.

In any case, once I click the button, Firefox console shows:

```
OnGetdata; loading ?getone via AJAX call      test_JSload.php:13:3
 ptest pre ajax is  Object {  }               test_JSload.php:16:3
TypeError: ptest.changeName is not a function test_JSload.php:31:3
got getone data                               test_JSload.php:21:7
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4:26272
 ptest post getone is  Object { firstName: "AHA", changeName: person/this.changeName(name) } test_JSload.php:24:7
```

Btw, the error '`TypeError: ... is not a function`' is the exact same I get from Mink/Zombie with the actual page I'm trying to inspect; although I don't think the page itself exhibits that error when called standalone, as it does here.

Now, let's try inspect this page with Mink (install as on [nodejs cannot find module 'zombie' with PHP mink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436666/nodejs-cannot-find-module-zombie-with-php-mink)):

**`test_JSload_mink.php`**

```php
<?php
$nodeModPath = "/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules";

# composer autoload:
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$zsrv = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer();
$zsrv->setNodeModulesPath($nodeModPath . "/"); # needs to end with a trailing '/'
$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver( $zsrv );
$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start the session
$session->start();

$session->visit("http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php");
$session->wait(20000, '(browser.statusCode > 0)'); ### THIS makes things work?!
$statcode = $session->getStatusCode();
echo "  current URL: " . $session->getCurrentUrl() ."\n";
echo "  status code: " . $statcode ."\n";

$page = $session->getPage();
$el_button = $page->findButton('getdatabtn');
echo "Check: el_b " . gettype($el_button) . "\n";

echo "  pressing/clicking the button\n";
$el_button->click();

echo "Page URL after click: ". $session->getCurrentUrl() . "\n";
?>
```

Running this from another terminal shell (while the first one still runs the php server process that serves `test_JSload.php`) results with:

```
$ php test_JSload_mink.php
  current URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php
  status code: 200
Check: el_b object
  pressing/clicking the button
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException' with message 'Error while processing event 'click': "ReferenceError: person is not defined\n    at Object.OnGetdata.$.ajax.success (http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php:script:16:19)\n    at i (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:27449)\n    at Object.j.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:28213)\n    at y (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4:22721)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.c (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4:26925)\n    at callListeners (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:170:34)\n    at dispatchPhase (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:159:7)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:115: in /media/Data1/work/bbs/gits/econdk-vis-01_git/test/test_php_mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/ZombieDriver.php on line 880
```

Now, here the error from Mink/Zombie is '`ReferenceError: person is not defined`', whereas in my actual page inspection, it is '`TypeError: ... is not a function`' - but I think they are similar enough.

The question is - how can I handle errors like this?

For instance, here there is already '`$session->wait(20000, '(browser.statusCode > 0)');`' used, which checks for `browser.statusCode` inside JavaScript; I'm aware there is also:

```
$returnstring = $session->evaluateScript('document.readyState');
```

... which can also ask for data from JavaScript. So something like this - in principle - could be used to "wait" until given resources are loaded.

But the problem here is that the `ptest` variable, which exposes the problem, is in the **local** scope of function `OnGetdata()`, and so I have no idea how to construct a statement that would "check" it from PHP - where I expect only global variables like `browser` and `document` to be accessible.

So, does anyone now how could I have a Mink/Zombie PHP script "wait" for such "nested" JavaScript loading - so I could complete the loading of the page, after the virtual click, without an error?

---

EDIT: Managed to reduce this problem to a plain Zombie JavaScript file:

**`test_JSload_zombie.js`**

```js
// call with:
// DEBUG=zombie NODE_PATH=/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules node test_JSload_zombie.js

var Browser = require("zombie");

browser = new Browser({waitDuration: 30*1000, runScripts: true});

browser.visit("http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php", function () {
  browser.pressButton('Get Data!'); //, done);
  console.log(' person, post-click pre-wait:', browser.evaluate('typeof(person)'), browser.evaluate('$("script").length') ); // $("script").length is 2
  var checkCondition = function () {
    var ret =browser.evaluate("(typeof(person) != 'undefined')");
    console.log("ret is " + ret);
    return ret;
  };
  browser.wait({function: checkCondition, duration: 100000}, function() {
    console.log(' person, post-wait:', browser.evaluate('typeof(person)'), browser.evaluate('$("script").length')); // $("script").length is 3
    /// browser.dump(); // not too much info
  });
});
```

Running this file, logs the exact same error:

```
  zombie Opened window http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php  +0ms
  zombie GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php => 200 +198ms
  zombie Loaded document http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php +233ms
  zombie GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js => 200 +207ms
  zombie Event loop is empty +476ms
OnGetdata; loading ?getone via AJAX call
 ptest pre ajax is  Object {}
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +54ms
  zombie XHR loadstart http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +3ms
  zombie TypeError: ptest.changeName is not a function
    at OnGetdata (http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php:script:24:9)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php:script:30:5)
    at n.event.dispatch (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3:12444)
    at r.handle (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3:9173)
    at callListeners (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:170:34)
    at dispatchPhase (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:159:7)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:115:3)
    at DOM.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/lib/dom/jsdom_patches.js:155:31)
    at define.proto.dispatchEvent (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:365:55)
    at Browser.fire (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/lib/index.js:424:14)
    in http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php +24ms
 person, post-click pre-wait: undefined 2
ret is false
  zombie GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone => 200 +36ms
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +7ms
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +0ms
ret is false
got getone data 
  zombie ReferenceError: person is not defined
    at Object.OnGetdata.$.ajax.success (http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php:script:16:19)
    at i (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:27449)
    at Object.j.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:28213)
    at y (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4:22721)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4:26925)
    at callListeners (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:170:34)
    at dispatchPhase (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:159:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/events/EventTarget.js:115:3)
    at XMLHttpRequest.DOM.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/lib/dom/jsdom_patches.js:155:31)
    at XMLHttpRequest._fire (/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/zombie/lib/xhr.js:242:12)
    in http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php +73ms
 person, post-wait: undefined 3
  zombie XHR readystatechange http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +4ms
  zombie XHR progress http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +0ms
  zombie XHR load http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +1ms
  zombie XHR loadend http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?getone +0ms
  zombie GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_JSload.php?gettwo => 200 +18ms
```

So, I guess if this gets solved on a Zombie/JS level, then it can eventually be solved on a Mink/PHP level... Note however, that the call to `?gettwo` happens only after the error has been emitted (and is the final entry in the log) - it seems that Zombie simply cannot wait for synchronous requests..

Comment: Have you tried to use a wait condition based on ajax requests like: $session->wait('numberOfSeconds', '(0 === Ajax.activeRequestCount)');   ?

Comment: Thanks for that, @lauda - just tried it, but I get: `ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined`. I looked it up a bit, and by this page: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/How-to-work-with-jQuery,-Prototype,-Dojo-AJAX I can see that `Ajax.activeRequestCount` is due to use of `prototypejs`, which I don't use anywhere in this example. I do use jQuery, and I tried `$session->wait(20000, '(0 === jQuery.active)');` before the `click()` instead, but it just fails the same as described in OP.

Comment: Try this too: $session->wait(50000, "document.readyState === 'complete'");   Or try other wait condition, for example a do while to wait for an object, also please not that findButton may return null if the element is not found/loaded so you can try a do-while for some seconds and if button !== null then break/return the button. I always use wait for element that returns the object or throws an exception and click, for example something like $this->waitForElement('selector')->click(); If you need an example of waitForElement please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
$session->wait(50000, "document.readyState === 'complete'");
```

Or try other wait condition, for example a do while to wait for an object, also please not that findButton may return null if the element is not found/loaded so you can try a do-while for some seconds and if button !== null then break/return the button.

I always use wait for element that returns the object or throws an exception and click, for example something like:

```
$this->waitForElement('selector')->click();
```

If you need an example of waitForElement please let me know.

Here are some ajax conditions that you can try [how-to-make-behat-wait-for-an-ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580813/how-to-make-behat-wait-for-an-ajax-call)