# remain at top of page on anchor #link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, settimeout

Im attempting to link to a page with a specific bootstrap nav-tabs open, I can achieve this simply by adding the tab id into a #link, eg:

www.mysite.com/apagewithtabs#tab2

This is great except for the page scrolls down to the where #tab2 appears, i'd like the user to be at the top of the page when it loads.

Ive tried many different variations of this following js/jquery but absolutely nothing is working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
  }, 2000);
});
```

If anyone has any ideas how I might be able to achieve this id really appreciate it!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many different methods unbelievably this works:

www.mysite.com/apagewithtabs#tab2#top

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted, so more will be guaranteed to see it if they need help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend appending the information you want via a query instead, like so:

`www.mysite.com/apagewithtabs?tab=tab2`

Then use this code to see what the tab query's value is:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var tab = getUrlVars()["tab"]; //tab is now the value of the tab query
```

*Partial code courtesy of [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)*

You can then check the value of the `tab` variable and open the whatever you desire based on what the value is. Example:

```
switch (tab) {
    case 'tab1': /*...open tab 1 code...*/ break;
    case 'tab2': /*...open tab 2 code...*/ break;
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your help, although still no luck here. Ive placed `<?php echo $tab; ?>` in the page but this is empty. Also currently I have no idea the js code to open a specific bootstrap tab?