# Javascript scope and sequentiality issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asynchronous

I want  to get an id from the query and display it in html.

I want to keep things in separate javascript files, because in the future, it will retrieve a json from php and will filter it based on some checkboxes, radio buttons, etc. and then display the result.

In this moment, I get a blank page, and the id value is not shown, so I'm doing something wrong.

```
http://localhost:10600/js1/index.php?id=5
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="display.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sequence.js"></script>
```

**config.js**

```
function getId() {
    id = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
}
```

**display.js**

```
function updateHtml() {
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = id;
}
}
```

**sequence.js**

```
function seq()
{
    getId();
    updateHtml();   
}
seq();
```

Comment: the URL for config.js has no id, therefore id=""

Comment: it should echo the id from the initial link: `ttp://localhost:10600/js1/index.php?id=5`

Comment: You cannot assign php value to js in .js file. You can assign only .php file

Comment: _it should echo the id from the initial link_ No, it shouldn't since `config.js` is a **separate** file

Comment: So if you need to get the id from your URL see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Comment: not necessarily so, @MathsRkBala

Comment: _You cannot assign php value to js in .js file._ Actually that's possible using some tricks such as URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:
**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var id;
function getId() {
    id = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="display.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sequence.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getParameters() {
    var url_params = window.location.search.substring(1); // Removing characters : ?
    var params = url_params.split("&");
    var res = {};

    for (var i = 0, c = params.length; i < c; i++) {
        var split = params[i].split("=");
        res[split[0]] = split[1];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Returns an object {param: value}

Answer (score 1):

In index.php within body you can do like this one

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
```

In JS :

If you are using jQuery,then you should do like this one.

```
$(document).ready(){ 
    var strHiddenId = $("#hidden_id").val();
    $(".results").html(strHiddenId);
}
```