# how to retrive values from database based on row id from url using php mysql json?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, url

Hi I am new to PHP JSON

**My URL**

http://xxxx.in/event-view.html?event_id=8

**My php code** (json-eventview.php)

```
    include "db.php";
    $data = array();
    $id = $_GET['event_id'];
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `ca_events` where ca_events.id=$id ");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
    $data[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

**and Javascript (get Json)** used in above url.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://localhost/php/json-eventview.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var id = field.id;
            var general_id = field.general_id;
            var name = field.name;
            var description = field.description;
            var agenda = field.agenda;
            var date = field.date;
            var time = field.time;
            $(".navbar-brand span").append(" " + name + " ");
        });
    });
});
```

the above gives an empty space.

If,
I remove $id = $_GET['event_id']; and WHERE in php file I get the entire table as result.

I need the column values of that particular id in url. can anyone help or give other ideas and examples to get the values based on id from url.

Comment: You need to pass your GET parameter to the url of your PHP page if you expect it to be in $_GET on that page.  `var url = "http://localhost/php/json-eventview.php";`  There is no GET parameter in that url.

Comment: Please don't interpolate user data into a SQL statement. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php :D

Comment: is your id is uniq?

Comment: yeah the id is uniq.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are passing GET data to an HTML form (Not a PHP or something else)

You need to add some jquery (Since I see Jquery code in your javascript) to pull out the event_id =8
Such as this location
[How to Read a URL from Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

Then Add it to your to the end of your .getJson URL.

Comment: as per your message i got this added to javascript var baseUrl = (window.location).href; var event_id = baseUrl.substring(baseUrl.lastIndexOf('=') + 1); alert(event_id) which alerts the id from url but how to get this id in php and get results in mysqli based on this id. Kindly clarify

Comment: store the id in an external variable (such as newid) and then put place it in the URL as "?event_id='.event_id"

Answer (score 0):

Change Javascript Code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = "http://localhost/php/json-eventview.php?event_id=YOUR_REQUESTED_ID";
```

and put your id insted of **YOUR_REQUESTED_ID**

Comment: I have two pages. events.html which has all the events listed. by clicking a event it should show the column values of that particular event in event-view.html, so how to put event id dynamically

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the problem is that the url parameter is on the page that has your `JavaScript`, and not on the `PHP` page that is receiving the `AJAX` call.  One way to resolve your problem would be to pass the event_id to your `PHP` page that receives the `AJAX` call.

On your page that has the `JavaScript`, parse the url to get the event_id parameter.

The function from [this site](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html) will parse your url for parameters:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
  };
  var eventId = getUrlParameter('event_id');
});
```

This will give you the event_id so that you can then use it in your AJAX call to the other PHP page:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/php/json-eventview.php?event_id="' + id + '"';
```

Your complete code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
  };
  var eventId = getUrlParameter('event_id');
  if(eventId !== undefined {
   var url = 'http://localhost/php/json-eventview.php?event_id="' + eventId + '"';
   $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        var id = field.id;
        var general_id = field.general_id;
        var name = field.name;
        var description = field.description;
        var agenda = field.agenda;
        var date = field.date;
        var time = field.time;
        $(".navbar-brand span").append(" " + name + " ");
    });
   });
  }
});
```

Comment: @SubramaniN - you can mark my response as the answer by selecting the checkmark icon near the top of my post.