# Getting query string parameters in a string with backslashes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need your help,

Given the following query string with backslashes in it:

```
"G:\\AS\\Asf\\ASF\\IMTS\\V11\\IMTS.hta?report=true&type=note"
```

How can I parse out the values of report and type?

example:

```
GetUrlParam('report') returns true

GetUrlParam('type') returns note
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "G:\\AS\\Asf\\ASF\\IMTS\\V11\\IMTS.hta?report=true&type=note";

function getUrlParam(param){
  var rg = new RegExp(param + "=(\\w+)"),
      res = str.match(rg)[1];
      console.log(res);
}

getUrlParam('report');
getUrlParam('type');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex `(?<=[\?&])([^=]+)=([^&]+)`? The first matching group is the parameter and the second matching group is the value.

Given your example, the matching groups are:

- Match 1
  `report=true`
  Group 1.    `report`
  Group 2.    `true`
- Match 2
  `type=note`
  Group 1.    `type`
  Group 2.    `note`

Answer (score 0):

I've modified an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656873/4760460) I've found on stackoverflow and have come up with this:

```js
var url = "G:\\AS\\Asf\\ASF\\IMTS\\V11\\IMTS.hta?report=true&type=note"

var vars = {}, hash;
var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  // starts query string after index of ? and splits query string based on &

for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
  hash = hashes[i].split('=');      // creates new array on each iteration (property and key)
  vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];      // add key value pair to object
}

console.log(vars);

function GetUrlParams(key) {
  if (typeof vars[key] !== 'undefined') {
    return vars[key];
  }
}

console.log(GetUrlParams('report'));
console.log(GetUrlParams('type'));
```