# Extract IDs from URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

The url of my website is in one of the following two formats:

```
Format 1: http://www.example.com/books/1309/angular-book
```

OR

```
Format 2: http://www.example.com/ShowBook.aspx?ID=1309
```

I can extract the entire URL using

```
var url = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
```

How can I extract the ID from the url (in this case "1309"), specifically when I do not know if the URL will appear as Format 1 or 2?

Comment: check these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115

Comment: It's not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks GG. It is not a duplicate. I tried changing my URL title but  charlietfl is hell bent on changing it back :)

Comment: It would help if you told us what frameworks you are using; both ASP.NET and jQuery have ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
url.match(/\d+/g) // One or more digits
```

With your examples:

```
"http://www.example.com/ShowBook.aspx?ID=1309".match(/\d+/g) // => ["1309"]

"http://www.example.com/books/1309/angular-book".match(/\d+/g) // => ["1309"]
```

Then you can `parseInt` the result.

Comment: Is there a way to pick the first digit that is encountered? Sometimes my cookie program may append a string of text after "ShowBook.aspx?ID=1309" which may contain a number too.

Comment: @IWantToLearn yes you just pick the first element of the array. Example: `"http://www.example.com/ShowBook.aspx?ID=1309&cookie=2576".match(/\d+/g) // => ["1309", "2576"]`

Comment: Thanks but how do I pick the first element of the array? Let us say I do var arr = url.match(match(/\d+/g)); parseInt(arr);

Comment: `var arr = url.match(/\d+/g); var id = parseInt(arr[0])`

Comment: Many thanks. Got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regexp to match only your urls format:

```
 /books\/(\d+)\/|ID=(\d+)/g
```

Using `\d+` will match any number in your urls, here is a working example:

```js
var url1 = 'http://www.example.com/books/1309/angular-book';
var url2 = 'http://www.example.com/ShowBook.aspx?ID=1309';

function getBookId(url) {
    var rexep = /books\/(\d+)\/|ID=(\d+)/g;
    var matches = rexep.exec(url);
    return matches[1] || matches[2];
}

console.log( getBookId(url1) );
console.log( getBookId(url2) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to pick the first digit that is encountered?

Comment: Yes of course, the regex above only returns digits that comes after `/books/` or `ID=`, try it

Comment: You can use a function to extract digits from the url, I updated my answer

Comment: Yes I can see it works well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, you can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url)

You can use this method:

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Usage:

```
getUrlVars()["ID"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dabbas. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code;

```js
var url = new URL("http://www.example.com/books/1309/angular-book");
//var url = new URL("http://www.example.com/ShowBook.aspx?ID=1309");
var id;
if(url.href.indexOf(".aspx") > -1)
{
   id = url.searchParams.get("ID");
}
else
{
   id = url.pathname.split("/")[2];
}
console.log(id);
```

Comment: Thanks. The snippet works.

Answer (score -1):

```
   function getID(){
        var url = window.location.href.split("/");
        if(url[3]==="books") return url[4];
        else { 
          url= window.location.href.split("?ID=");
          return url[1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks workable!