# Get Querystring values in an array

Tags: jquery

Could someone help me to get the querystring in an array on page reload
Here is an example of the querystring
https://local.abc.com/?country=us&state=California&city=Los%20Angeles&city=abc%20Plan&city=xyz

I need to get the list of city from the querystring to further perform some action on the city list.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get querystring from URL using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/get-querystring-from-url-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting one code row from [Get querystring from URL using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/get-querystring-from-url-using-jquery) here is result:

```
var cities = [];
var a = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (i in a) {
    var n = a[i].split("=");
    if (n[0].toUpperCase() == "CITY") {
        cities.push(decodeURIComponent(n[1]));
    }
}
console.log(cities);
```

cities is the array containing all cities from URI