# How to pass search parameter to datatables Search field

Tags: javascript, css

I have successfully setup datatables (with no search text by default). I want to be able to pass a search parameter to my datatbles table via URL. for example if my default datatables page is abc.html. I want to add search text "test" via url abc.html?search.search=test

I am not sure how I can do this. Please see the code I have on the datatables page below.

http://live.datatables.net/nitozucu/1/edit

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

  responsive: true,
  paging: false,
  searching: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  bInfo: false,
  bSort: true,
 
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />

  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>Tiger Nixon</td>
<td>System Architect</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>61</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Garrett Winters</td>
<td>Accountant</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>63</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Ashton Cox</td>
<td>Junior Technical Author</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>66</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">AAAA</a></td>
<td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></td>
<td>Accountant</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>33</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Google</a></td>
<td>Integration Specialist</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>61</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Test</a></td>
<td>Sales Assistant</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>59</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">BBBB</a></td>
<td>Integration Specialist</td>
<td>Tokyo</td>
<td>55</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Colleen Hurst</td>
<td>Javascript Developer</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>39</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Sonya Frost</td>
<td>Software Engineer</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Jena Gaines</td>
<td>Office Manager</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: You should also include relevant code here.

Comment: Updated to include code.

Comment: I suggest adding the [tag:jquery] tag because your code specifically uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use some backend (e.g. php, jsp, .NET etc) to process the query string before loading the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

  responsive: true,
  paging: false,
  searching: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  bInfo: false,
  bSort: true,
  search: {
    search: "<%= preprocessedQueryStringHere %>"
  }
 });
});
```

or use some javascript framework (e.g. jQuery, ReactJS, Angular etc) to extract the query string and pass it into your DataTable search term.
[example on how to get query string using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/get-querystring-from-url-using-jquery)

you can replace your javascript with the following, and try abc.html?search=san

```
function getUrlVars() {
      var vars = [], hash;
      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
      for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
      {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
      return vars;
  } 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var searchTerm = getUrlVars()['search'];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      responsive: true,
      paging: false,
      searching: true,
      lengthChange: false,
      bInfo: false,
      bSort: true,
      search: {
        search: searchTerm
      }
   });
  });
```

Comment: This worked!! Thankyou very much.

Comment: This worked!! Thankyou very much. You are awesome.
Another question. How do I edit the javascript to filter on specific column?

Example: abc.com?search=san&division=policy
Note: Division here refers to the column name.

Comment: You can try to incorporate getUrlVars()['division'] into 
[DataTable individual column search](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. I will open a seperate question. Thanks again.